# Ambiguous call services.AddOptions() in ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

After adding `services.AddOptions()` in `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` the following error occurs:

```
CS0121  
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.OptionsServiceCollectionExtensions.AddOptions(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection) and Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.OptionsServiceCollectionExtensions.AddOptions(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection)'
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

...

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddOptions();
    ...
}
```

This is particularly strange as the ambiguity is between the same 'methods or properites'

Comment: That it is the same type, could just mean that this type is defined in two assemblies you both have referenced. Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36769984/21567)?

Comment: Yes, thanks @Christian.K. Will track it on the previous one. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on the feedback from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36769984/aspnet-core-pre-rc2-dependency-ambiguity) I tracked down that I had a reference in `project.lock.json` to `"EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final"` which on its own has a reference to `"Microsoft.Extensions.OptionsModel": "1.0.0-rc1-final"`

The whole point is to have only references to `"Microsoft.Extensions.Options": "1.0.0-rc2-final"` and remove all the ones to `OptionsModel`.